# How to instantiate menu object?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying to hide and show a menu item in my action bar.

when i click on the menu item, i run a function called showAddFrag(). Inside that function I am trying to hide the menu item. so my code is something like this

```
public void showAddFrag(){
Menu menu = new Menu (); // giving me this error: "Cannot instantiate the type Menu"
menu.findItem(R.id.add_item).setVisible(false); //hiding the add_item menu item
....
}
```

I know I am doing it wrong, but can someone point me in the right direction. Is there a function that I can reference to the context menu object?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this callback: onPrepareOptionsMenu() and this method: menu.findItem(..) to save your button as an instance variable

Then set an onClickListener for your button that will disable it once clicked. And enable it back when you have to.

I hope this is what you're trying to do

Comment: I basically just created a Menu variable global and reference it when I need it...